# SMS bug: "@" at the end of messages

Tags: sms, bugs

I recently started receiving a lot of messages ending with the "@" character. I asked why and they said they weren't doing that. We both use android, both use Textra, and  I checked in other SMS apps too and there were still "@" symbols on my end. Its not every message either, just random ones.  What could possibly cause this bug?

Comment: I've started getting B001 at the end of all messages from servers, like banks and mobile service providers